# ReactJs Package

Tags: reactjs, package

I have created a package with multiple components and exported it in it's index.js file. I am trying to 
  import those components and us it. as follows:

```
  **package index.js**
   export {default as F1Button } from './f1Button';
   export {F1ButtonGroup} from './f1ButtonGroup';
   export {F1Label} from './f1Label';

    **Used it in New.js**
    import { F1Button,F1ButtonGroup,F1Label } from 'package';
     function App() {
        return (
         <div className="App">
         <F1Button name='test' buttonText="hi"></F1Button>
         <F1ButtonGroup symbols={symbols}></F1ButtonGroup>
         <F1Label text="label"></F1Label>
        </div>
       );
       }
```

```
Getting error as : 
 Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) 
 or a class/function (for 
 composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your 
 component from the file 
 it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
  Check the render method of `App`.
```

How to export multiple components in index.js and import it our file?

Answer (score 0):

Exporting a single component as default

```
export default sample
```

Exporting multiple components

```
export {
  sample1,
  sample2
}
```

Importing a default component (here its not required to import as the same name)

```
import Hello from './sample'
```

Importing Multiple components (you need to use the exact name of export)

```
import {sample1, sample2} from './sample'
```

Comment: F1Label, F1Button are my different components, each having export statement as 
  follows
```````
    export default F1Button ----------------- In F1Button component
    export default F1Label--------------------In F1Label component.
     as below in index.js of package.
     export { F1Button } from './f1Button';
     export { F1Label } from './f1Label';
 And I am importing it as 
   import {F1Button , F1Label} from './package'
``````````
  It is giving the same error.
 How to do it?